# Remove HTML Tags from a text using SQL

Tags: sql, oracle

I have column in a table which contains HTML text(data contains HTML tags) and also normal text.

I need to remove the HTML tags in the data wherever it exists.

**Steps I planned:**

1. Filter only the records which contains HTML tags. --> I am able to complete this step. My Logic: where HTMLStirng like('<%>%')
2. Replace HTML tags with a blank space. --> I am trying to apply replace function. But I am not able to.

For Example:

```
<p>Paragraph</p>
<b>bold</b><I>Italic</I>
Normal Text
```

My Output shold be:

```
Paragraph
BoldItalic
Normal Text
```

Can someone help me in the step 2 ?

Comment: I removed the incompatible database tags.  Tag your questions only with the database you are actually using.

Comment: This is crazy and deep in XY territory.

Comment: `I am trying to apply replace function. But I am not able to.` ...why didn't those replacements  work for you?

Comment: which database are you using, `sql server` or  `oracle` or anything else?

Answer (score 4):

If you are using Oracle, try the following

```
SELECT Regexp_replace(your_column_name, '<.+?>') 
FROM   dual;
```

Example

```
SELECT Regexp_replace('<b>bold</b><I>Italic</I> Testing', '<.+?>') 
FROM   dual;
```